# Send and receive data from mbed to android

Tags: android, bluetooth, transfer, mbed

I'm trying to create an `mbed LPC1768` application which communicates with my phone (Huawei). I have already done an app which connects both with Bluetooth and it works! (I just can turn on/off mbed's led with my phone)

But now I'm trying to send and receive data (for example, words) to `mbed`, for example "hello" and receive "HELLO" but I don't know how to do it, I'm blocked. Please, could someone give any help? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the UART demo application, it opens up a bi-directional channel that allows you to send data back and forth. In essence you create two characteristics, one is write-able one is read-able, and use those to send data.

Comment: Few android devices have accessible UARTs.  You might manage something along these lines over USB transport, but most of the key pieces are missing from your answer.

Comment: I have already try your idea but It doesn't work. When I'm scanning devices the phone can't find the bluetooth. With the other app can. I don't know what happens

Comment: Then my best answer would be to use a board that has BLE on it, like the Nordic nRF51 EK or DK (10/25$ USD respectively). The BLE boards supported by mbed have several examples, one of which is how to setup a UART channel over BLE. Also examples on how to control LED's and other cool schenanigans.

If you are tied to the LPC1768 then either root your android device so you can do USB COM (serial channel) or you can try to figure out how to do UART using the Bluetooth component you have. Providing details about the component would be helpful here.